# Referencing (\cite) order conflicting with Table of Figures

Tags: table-of-contents, citing, texmaker

I am using LaTeX package for a documentation. The figures in the text have references in their captions. Due to the 'List of Figures' section being present in the beginning of the Document, the citation order is initialising at this section.

Eg.

The first figure with a citation in its caption is on Page 10. The citation should be [7], but as it is the first figure in the document, and the List of Figures section is at the beginning, the citation in the caption is [1].

Kindly assist